# how can i cover return statement in test class

Tags: method

```
public static string hasCreate(String systemid,String selectObject){
    system.debug('called');
        try{
        Object_Configuaration__c Childs=[SELECT ID,Operations__c, Name,Object_Name__c, Source_System_Configuaration__r.id, Source_System_Configuaration__r.Name,Source_System_Configuaration__r.System_Id__c
    FROM Object_Configuaration__c where Source_System_Configuaration__r.System_Id__c=:systemid and Operations__c='Create' and Object_Name__c=:selectObject];
        system.debug('hfy'+Childs.Object_Name__c);
        System.debug('jvnytgt'+selectObject);

    }catch(Exception e){
        system.debug(e);
        system.debug('sys'+systemid);
        return '0';
    }
    return '1';
}
```

[image]

hi,need help,how can cover that return '1' in my test class,thanks in advance

Comment: this is always going into catch block...just add LIMIT 1 to your query, and it would cover both the blocks based on query results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

```
public static string hasCreate(String systemid,String selectObject){
    system.debug('called');
        try{
        Object_Configuaration__c Childs=[SELECT ID,Operations__c, Name,Object_Name__c, Source_System_Configuaration__r.id, Source_System_Configuaration__r.Name,Source_System_Configuaration__r.System_Id__c
    FROM Object_Configuaration__c where Source_System_Configuaration__r.System_Id__c=:systemid and Operations__c='Create' and Object_Name__c=:selectObject LIMIT 1];    
    }catch(Exception e){
        system.debug(e);
        system.debug('sys'+systemid);
        return '0';
    }
    return '1';
}
```

I added LIMIT 1 to the query so that the query result can be assigned to a single Object. You could also assign the result to a list as a suggested best practice.

If the query returns result, the return would be '1'. else, it  would return '0'

Answer (score 0):

A good part of the question would have been to post the error as it would have been helpful but....

I assume you are getting the error because you are returning a list of results but trying to assign to an sObject?

Simply change your declaration to a list type:

```
Object_Configuaration__c[] Childs = [Select .... ];
```

and your debug statements to:

```
system.debug('listofChilds[0]'+Childs[0].Operations__c);
        system.debug('hfy'+Childs[0].Object_Name__c);
```